# SQL Alchemy 2.0 reflecting Oracle table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-oracledb

I was trying to find but wihtout luck whether this question had been asked for SQL Alchemy 2.0+ as all I could find were older versions.

I'm connecting fine to Oracle and can query just by executing `text("sql script")`

Connection is

```
engine = create_engine(f"oracle+oracledb://{user}:{pass}@{dsn}",echo='debug')
```

As I said this connects fine. After this all I have is:

```
meta = MetaData()
table = Table(name, meta, schema='user', autoload_with=engine)
```

So right now all I want to do is reflect that table. I've been doing similar with SQL server DB and it's been fine, no issues at all. However when this above runs I get

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: name
```

I get that above despite the fact that from debug I can see that the SQL it's running against Oracle to get the Metadata and is actually returning everything it should. In the query it runs against all_tab_cols in Oracle it returns the table all the cols, datatypes etc. The query to get indexes etc returns everything for that table.

I also tried as the docstrings in reflection.py for reflect_table

```
engine = create_engine('...')
meta = MetaData()
table = Table('user', meta)
insp = inspect(engine)
insp.reflect_table(table, None)
```

Again same error despite all SQL it seems to be running in Oracle to get the info was returning results for that table.

Comment: Does the table have a primary key?

Comment: Yep, pulls all that out fine according to the log

Comment: Is there anything in `metadata.tables ` after reflection?

Comment: By chance does `name` contatn a multi-part name like `MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE`?

Comment: haha thanks to that question I solved it. So yes I checked the tables from metadata returned and it returned it in lowercase despite being upper case in the DB. So I changed the casing of the table name i was sending to table reflection to lower case not as per Oracle and now table reflection works.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was that I should always be passing lowercase table name to table reflection regardless of the casing in OracleDB

Comment: "regardless of the casing in OracleDB" - Not quite true. `CREATE TABLE thing …` creates a table named `THING` which SQLAlchemy will normalize back to `thing`, but `CREATE TABLE "SomeOtherTable" …` creates a table named `SomeOtherTable` which SQLAlchemy will recognize as-is. When in doubt, check what is returned by the `.get_table_names()` inspection function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).